# Recursive hierarchical PGSQL request with uuid goes into a loop

Tags: postgresql

Helle there

I'd like to get a hierarchical data parent / childs. meaning that if i select tje id of the parent, all its chilren will be in the record
Their relations are defined by the parent UUID

I have in a DB the following data :

```
INSERT INTO dummy_table (Id, parent) VALUES ('0171a28a-578a-49b5-86d5-ff0df54c8e96', '0171a28a-578a-49b5-86d5-ff0df54c8e96')
INSERT INTO dummy_table (Id, parent) VALUES ('0171a28a-5809-4708-9fc9-aeb91c16e560', '0171a28a-578a-49b5-86d5-ff0df54c8e96')
INSERT INTO dummy_table (Id, parent) VALUES ('0171a28a-580b-4de9-b3fa-35f13df27dd5', '0171a28a-5809-4708-9fc9-aeb91c16e560')
INSERT INTO dummy_table (Id, parent) VALUES ('0171a28a-580c-4e6b-8d17-0cc18af24b25', '0171a28a-580b-4de9-b3fa-35f13df27dd5')
INSERT INTO dummy_table (Id, parent) VALUES ('0171a28a-580d-47ee-aa15-92c6727e657e', '0171a28a-580c-4e6b-8d17-0cc18af24b25')
```

And my request is the following :

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, parent FROM dummy_table WHERE id = '0171a28a-578a-49b5-86d5-ff0df54c8e96'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT dt.id, dt.parent FROM dummy_table dt INNER JOIN cte ON cte.parent = dt.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

The problem i have is that it loops and I cannot figure out why.

Any help please ?

Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query goes into a loop because the first row in your data references itself as its parent and so the recursion never stops. Add a check to avoid self-reference and you should be fine

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, parent FROM dummy_table WHERE id = '0171a28a-578a-49b5-86d5-ff0df54c8e96'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt.id, dt.parent FROM dummy_table dt INNER JOIN cte ON cte.parent = dt.id and cte.id <> dt.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Another option is setting parent as null in the rows where parent is equal to id

Comment: That's one of the reasons why setting the parent to `NULL` is a better approach than letting it reference the same id